# Replace groups of characters by carriage return

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a line with `', '` in my file, and I want to replace this with an `new line`, and delete `['` and `']`

I have tried this:

```
sed -e 's/$/\r/' file.txt
```

But I didn't get the right result:

***file.txt:***

```
['site1|10.29.16.53|10.29.0.0|19|FRMER / New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)', 'site2|10.19.15.3|10.19.135.0|26|FRMER / certificat|Vlan 754', 'site 3|10.9.16.24|10.9.0.0|19|FMER / certificat|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)', 'site9|10.12.15.13|10.1.5.0|26|FRER / certificat| bopreprodback  Vlan 754', 'site4|10.29.4.2|10.9.0.0|19|FRR / certificat|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)']
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you are expecting. Your `sed` command is just adding a `\r` to the end of the line, that isn't replacing the `','`. Are you just looking for `sed "s/\['//; s/\]'//; s/$/\r/`?

Comment: Is your data originally a JSON array?

Comment: You have multiple copies of `', '`, but you say "replace this" (singular). Are you sure you want a carriage return, and not a newline (line feed) to split that into multiple lines?

Comment: You are still not showing your expected output. We can't help you if we can't understand what you need.

Comment: @Kusalananda, apparently not, because it uses single quotes. As far as I can find, only double quotes are standard (and `jq` doesn't seem to eat the single quotes.)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes i want a new line sorry for my first post

Answer (score -1):

Your input is in the legal syntax for creating an "anonymous array reference" in perl, so you can exploit that:

```
perl -lne 'print for @{eval $_}' file

site1|10.29.16.53|10.29.0.0|19|FRMER / New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)
site2|10.19.15.3|10.19.135.0|26|FRMER / certificat|Vlan 754
site 3|10.9.16.24|10.9.0.0|19|FMER / certificat|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)
site9|10.12.15.13|10.1.5.0|26|FRER / certificat| bopreprodback  Vlan 754
site4|10.29.4.2|10.9.0.0|19|FRR / certificat|BACKUP_MUT_SD  Vlan981 (PVLAN 1981)  New Backup Subnet #1  (site SD)
```

Take care what data you pass to it; since it's calling `eval`, a malicious file may wipe your files or destroy your marriage.